# Acomodar el div para que todos sean del mismo tamaño

Tags: php, html5, laravel, bootstrap

Tengo varios card, pero cada uno tienen textos distintos, pero quiero que todos tengan la misma cantidad de texto, para que con el "leer mas" se muestre luego solo, aunque eso es otra cosa. simplemente lo que quiero es que solo aparezca cierta cantidad de texto para poder que sea simetrico y todos del mismo tamaño.

> Asi los tengo yo
>   [image: Imagen de la web]

este es mi codigo:

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $message->image }}" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
        <small class="text-muted">Escrito por <a href="/{{ $message->user->username }}">{{ $message->user->name }}</a></small>
        <p class="card-text">
            {{ $message->content }}
            <a href="/messages/{{ $message->id }}">Leer más</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted float-rightcuarderno de refuerzo lapiz">{{ $message->created_at }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

Quiero que todos tengan la misma longitud de texto

Comment: probaste con un `split`? Especificas que corte la cadena cuando encuentre _espacios_ y después unificas la cantidad que quieras... es lo que se me ocurre

Comment: si buena idea, creo que split puede funcionar, voy a buscar mas sobre ello

Comment: Utilizas alguna librería tipo `jQuery` o `AngularJS`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Puedes usar al Helper [str_limit](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/helpers#method-str-limit) de laravel que justamente hace lo que necesitas:

Queraria algo asi:

```
<div class="card">
    <img class="card-img-top" src="{{ $message->image }}" alt="">
    <div class="card-body">
        <small class="text-muted">Escrito por <a href="/{{ $message->user->username }}">{{ $message->user->name }}</a></small>
        <p class="card-text">
            {{ str_limit($message->content, 50, '...') }}
            <a href="/messages/{{ $message->id }}">Leer más</a>
        </p>
    </div>
    <div class="card-footer">
        <small class="text-muted float-rightcuarderno de refuerzo lapiz">{{ $message->created_at }}</small>
    </div>
</div>
```

En este caso use `{{ str_limit($message->content, 50, '...') }}` por lo que te trunca el texto a solo 50 caracteres y le agregar los puntos suspensivos al final.

Comment: Gracias amigo, este me funciono a la perfeccion y es muy simple

Answer (score 1):

Con esta función cuenta las palabras que le indiques y omite o corta el texto hasta ese limite.

```
function wordlimit($string, $length, $ellipsis = "...")
{
$words = explode(' ', $string);
if (count($words) > $length)
{
        return implode(' ', array_slice($words, 0, $length)) ." ". $ellipsis;
}
else
{
        return $string;
}

}
```

Solamente llámala de la siguiente forma.

```
$string = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum";

echo $cutText = wordlimit($string, 15);
```

El primer valor es tu cadena de texto y el segundo el limite de palabras a mostrar y te agrega tres puntos después de tu limite establecido.

Ademas te recomiendo darle un alto fijo con CSS a tus `DIV` para que todos queden del mismo tamaño.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la propiedad [text-overflow](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_text-overflow.asp) y [white-space](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_text_white-space.asp) de CSS3 para solo mostrar una línea de tu texto y unos puntos suspensivos al final si aún falta texto.

```css
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  -o-text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Title of the document</title>
</head>

<body>
  <h5>TEXTO ACORTADO:</h5>
  <div class="ellipsis">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
  <hr>
  <h5>TEXTO COMPLETO</h5>
  <div>
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Si quisieras que sea más de una línea puedes consultar este [artículo](https://css-tricks.com/line-clampin/).